# Multiple return type(Array<string> | Boolean) for arrow function

Tags: typescript

I have an arrow function in a class that returns either array or boolean:

```
class A{

   myfunction=(val:number):Array<string>|Boolean=>{
     return number>1000?true:["jack","robin","harry"];
   }
}
```

and I want to call the function as:

```
const myclass=new A();

const arr=myclass.myfunction(10);

if(typeof arr==="boolean"){
  console.log("dami");
}else{
   if(arr.indexOf("harry")>0){
          ##here at indexOf i get an error :Property 'indexOf' does not exist on type 'Boolean | string[]'.
     console.log("we found harry");
   }
}
```

Calling `indexOf` gives an error saying : `Property 'indexOf' does not exist on type 'Boolean | string[]'.` What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Capital B `Boolean` is not the same as lowercase b `boolean`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return type should refer to the primitive `boolean` type:

```
Array<string> | boolean // or string[] | boolean
```

And not the object `Boolean` type:

```
Array<string> | Boolean
```

As the [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html) notes:

> The type names `String`, `Number`, and `Boolean` (starting with capital
> letters) are legal, but refer to some special built-in types that will
> very rarely appear in your code. Always use `string`, `number`, or `boolean`
> for types.